# Rails: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Team() Expected, got String()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I ran into this error while trying to solve a "Chicken and egg" problem with users and teams in my code. I've scoured the internet, and this seems to be a common error with none of the solutions making sense given my situation.

## Minimum Viable Example:

On the rails console, I made a new (invalid) user:

```
user = User.new(name: "sudo", email: "foo@example.com")
```

Then a valid team:

```
team = Team.new( name: "Test team, please ignore", tier: 0, owner: user.id, users: user.id)
```

Grab the ID:

```
id = team.save
```

Then tried to make a valid user:

```
user = User.new(name: "sudo", email: "foo@example.com", team: id)
```

Output of these commands are respectively:

```
=> #<User id: nil, name: "sudo", email: "foo@example.com", team_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
=> #<Team id: nil, name: "Test team, please ignore", tier: 0, owner: nil, users: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Team(#47180498893940) expected, got TrueClass(#47180477068240)
```

If I try to use `team.id`, I get the same error with "String()" instead of "TrueClass"

**I am using enable_extension "uuid-ossp"**, so the ID's should not be sequential.

I'm confused in both situations as to why the ID's are nil, or why the mismatch is `"Team(##47180498893940)"` and not `"52b9f290-61e7-48b3-99a9-b0fb64d68b51"` as the output of `team.id` would suggest.

## Tests:

My tests also give the string error:

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
   def setup
    @team = Team.new(name: "Example Team", tier: 0, owner: "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", team: team_id)
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end
end
```

## Models:

Team:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user
    has_one :owner
end
```

User:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to:team
end
```

## Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170213070551) do

# These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
enable_extension "plpgsql"
enable_extension "uuid-ossp"

create_table "teams", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "tier"
  t.string   "owner"
  t.string   "users"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "users", id: :uuid, default: -> { "uuid_generate_v4()" }, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.string   "team_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
end
```

If there is any more information I can provide, please let me know. I am inexperienced in rails app development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
user = User.new(name: "sudo", email: "foo@example.com", team: team)
```

since in `id = team.save`, it will store either `true` or `false`. Depending on if the code successfully saved the object or any error happened like validation error, it will return `true` or `false` respectively.

If you want to save with ID then try something like below:

```
team = Team.new(...) # create team with right attributes inside `new`
team.save
user = User.new(name: "sudo", email: "foo@example.com", team_id: team.id) # notice the `team_id`
```

Since you will be saving by id, you should use the forign_key column name directly. Otherwise if you use `team` attribute then you will have to supply a `Team` object not an integer object like id (ex. 21).

Comment: Wow, I was really just over thinking it?

Since you were so fast on the draw - mind helping me with one more thing? (I'll mark you as the answer in 9 more minutes)

`NameError: uninitialized constant Team::Owner` 

How can I solve this chicken and egg problem?

I can't make a user without a team, and I can't make a team without an owner. Is there such a thing as a "null" uuid?

Comment: You did not post your `Owner` model but still I guess there should not be any problem in creating Owner first since your team has one owner not a belongs_to association. And I guess the error you posted is coming from some other place. Might need more detail on structure and model codes. about null "uuid" , i dont have much idea but you can disable validation for presence in `belongs_to` in config.

Comment: The "owner" is just a user, it should be set to the id of a team member. (I haven't implemented the validation of this)

So the owner model is just the user model.

The error I posted is coming from the "Test" I posted above.

Comment: You have not defined owner class yet or associated it properly that's why it throws error. If the Owner is just a user then in Team class, try something like `has_one :owner, class_name: 'User'` .